# Implementing a sort column in Postgres that acts like a linked list

Tags: postgresql, linked-list

Say I have a database table `teams` that has an ordering column `position`, the position can either be `null` if it is the last result, or the id of next `team` that is positioned one higher than that team. This would result in a list that is always strictly sorted (if you use ints you have to manage all the other position values when inserting a new `team`, ie increment them all by one), and the insertion becomes less complicated...

But to retrieve this table as a sorted query has proved tricky, here is where I'm at so far:

```
WITH RECURSIVE teams AS (  
  SELECT *, 1 as depth FROM team
  UNION
  SELECT t.*, ts.depth + 1 as depth
  FROM team t INNER JOIN teams ts ON ts.order = t.id 
SELECT
  id, order, depth
FROM
  teams
;
```

Which gets me something like:

```
 id | order | depth
----+-------+-------
 53 |    55 |     1
 55 |    52 |     1
 55 |    52 |     2 
 52 |    54 |     2
 52 |    54 |     3
 54 |       |     3
 54 |       |     4
```

Which kind of reflects where I need to get to in terms of ordering (the max of depth represents the ordering I want...) however I cant work out how to alter the query to get something like:

```
 id | order | depth
----+-------+-------
 53 |    55 |     1
 55 |    52 |     2 
 52 |    54 |     3
 54 |       |     4
```

It seems however I change the query it complains at me about applying a `GROUP BY` across both `id` and `depth`... How do I get from where I am now to where I want to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your recursive query should to start somewhere (for now you selecting whole table in the first subquery). I propose to start from the last record where `order` column is null and walk to the first record:

```
with recursive team(id, ord) as (values(53,55),(55,52),(52,54),(54,null)),
  teams as (
    select *, 1 as depth from team where ord is null -- select the last record here
    union all
    select t.*, ts.depth + 1 as depth
    from team t join teams ts on ts.id = t.ord) -- note that the JOIN condition reversed comparing to the original query
select * from teams order by depth desc; -- finally reverse the order
```

```
┌────┬──────┬───────┐
│ id │ ord  │ depth │
├────┼──────┼───────┤
│ 53 │   55 │     4 │
│ 55 │   52 │     3 │
│ 52 │   54 │     2 │
│ 54 │ ░░░░ │     1 │
└────┴──────┴───────┘
```

Comment: `border 2`, `linestyle unicode` and `null ` give smth similar, but still with vertical `|` istead of line - how do you draw your table?.. I know its not related, but please - share

Comment: @VaoTsun Here is content of my `.psqlrc`: https://pastebin.com/9MEipXCz and how it looks like: http://i2.imageban.ru/out/2018/05/02/ae11d40c306025a64d7b55e88457ec87.png Hope it will helpful.

Comment: Thank you! Alas I must need some extended support for unicode or smth.